# Why can't modify the Integer instance in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(1);
a.add(2);
System.out.println(a.get(0));
a.get(0) = 10;
```

It gives an error:

> variable expected

But if I do not use classes declared by myself, I can easily modify the elements. Why?

Comment: `a.get` is a _getter_. If you want to _set_ an element, use `a.set(0, 10)`. You cannot assign something to a method call in Java.

Comment: Integer is immutable. You are just assigning a new object reference to it

Comment: First of all: you're using an ArrayList and not a HashSet

Comment: `a.get(0) = 10;` is not valid Java. You can't assign anything by using `a.get()`.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the question is being downvoted. Of course, there is likely a duplicate, but if that was the case, why not flag as such? We all had to start somewhere, right?

Comment: @AustinSchäfer for one the title says `HashSet` and he's using `ArrayList`, secondly the `a.get(0) = 10;` is an elementary level syntax error, thirdly the last sentence doesn't make any sense. You couldn't do that even if you were using your own classes instead of `Integer`. Searching for a duplicate for something like this would be a waste of time, and I can't even start to imagine what would be a suitable duplicate for such a bad question.

Comment: @Kayaman sorry for the mistakes I make. It may make sense in CPP. I do not realize that Java has no operator overloading for '=', and Integer a = 10 is just a condensed expression for "Integer a = new Integer(10)".

Comment: If you're used to another C-like language the syntax can play tricks. Especially here where you've got autoboxing and `Integer` immutability involved.

Answer (score 1):

As many others have stated in the comments a.get(0) returns the first item in index 0 of the list. **to override an element in the 0th index you must do the following.**

```
a.set(index, data-type);
a.set(0, 10);
```

Comment: sorry, I think that a.set method does a replace operation, rather than a modification. The key point I think is Integer is immutable. what do you think